# Aftermarket keyless entry remote locks but does not unlock

Tags: toyota, fob, aftermarket-upgrade, remote-start, venza

There is an aftermarket remote start and keyless remote system that came installed on a used vehicle we bought, but I have not understood how to make it work properly.

It always works to lock the doors, but usually does not unlock.

Also, most times it seems to lack a visual or audible indication from the vehicle when receiving commands and/or executing them.

I found instructions on entering and exiting a valet mode which seemed to let the remote unlock immediately after this, but at some point it stops working again, I think after the first drive.

The original factory remote always works fine. However I only have one, and I'd like to use the aftermarket remotes as extras/spares.

Thoughts on how to get the aftermarket remote working reliably?

Model: Vizion VZ1WAMR-960

Manual: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/469154/Firstech-1wamr-Fiance.html

Vehicle: 2009 Toyota Venza (without smart key system)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The button for the unlock is probably bad.

Comment: @narkeleptk I checked and cleaned the underside of the buttons and didn't see issues. Also, it's not intermittent. I think it could be a programming issue, because the car seems to receive the command and makes a slight noise in some relay but does not unlock the doors.

Comment: If the online manual doesn't have complete descriptions for wiring, system check and operation, can you contact manufacturer tech support? If not, perhaps a simple workaround is to use the factory remote and use the aftermarket remote for remote starting. Some aftermarket remote start systems allow modifying the factory remote for remote starting via programming to eliminate carrying two remotes.

Comment: @FDryer No, the manual doesn't have wiring or system diagrams, and I'm not sure if it applies exactly to the model I have. I am not using the remote start feature. I would just like to use it to lock and unlock doors and open the power rear door if possible. The issue is that the unlock typically does not work. Listening to relay and door lock sounds, It's almost as if the car starts unlocking then immediately re-locks the doors, which makes me think it's stuck in some valet mode.

Comment: Your post states "The OEM remote always works fine." My assumption is this means the original factory remote(s). If this is correct, can you use it/them instead of the aftermarket remotes?

Comment: @FDryer Yes, by OEM I meant the original factory remote. Yes I can and do use it, but there is only one and I'd like to be able to use the aftermarket remotes as extras/spares.

Comment: Some vehicles have diy programmable remotes. Some rfid ignition keys (embedded with a microchip transponder are also diy friendly when replacing remotes. Owner's manuals have information as a first source of facts. Service manuals are second. Some dealers (unethical ones), online sites have facts and disinformation and difficult to discern unless familiar with vehicle antitheft systems. I have an older GM vehicle approaching 20yrs), requiring either GMs scantool or aftermarket scantool to program replacement remotes. I bought a scantool to; decode all GM error codes and program spare remotes.

Comment: @FDryer Ok, but I'm not trying to program factory remotes. Just trying to get the aftermarket remotes to function as I would expect. Maybe I missed some procedure and/or don't understand the valet mode, as I'm not familiar with aftermarket remote start devices.

Comment: Well, you're left with some options but may have to spend time determining costs of buying a spare remote and programming for a spare, finding the shop that installed the aftermarket remote start and inquiring about repairs to the remote or replacing the   remote, finding the operating manual for the aftermarket remote for info.  There may be online sources for your aftermarket remote start system.

Comment: @FDryer Before all that... I just want to understand how the aftermarket remote works. There might be nothing wrong and I just don't understand how to use it. Today it worked to lock and unlock the doors before a trip, and also worked to unlock after using the remote start. But later unlock did not work until after remote starting the vehicle. I'm not sure how this system works, as I don't have the original manual, and the online manual I found is general to a large number of remotes.

Comment: Perhaps one of these links can help. All  provide free manuals for your VZi-WAMR-960; https://www.bobsmanuals.com/Automotive/Security/Firstech/VZ1WAMR-960/manual/download/ and https://www.manualslib.com/products/Firstech-Vz1wamr-960-2816269.html

Comment: @FDryer Both of those links appear to be for the same manual I posted originally in the question. It's entirely possible I'm just not understanding the content, perhaps partly because the manual is written with information that may or may not apply for many models, and not specifically for the VZ1WAMR-960 model I have.